# NetBeans 7.1.2 doesn't find *.jsp files on "Go To File..."

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I've started to face something somewhat weird in my IDE.
I this project, we have some **branches** and the **trunk** version, as known.

Since the beginning, I could find any files in any project openned by the command **Alt + Shift + O** (Go to File ...) and everything worked correctly.

But suddenly (I swear that I do not know why or how or when), NetBeans stopped to find ***.jsp** files by the shortcut aforementioned with the **trunk** openned. It finds only the files that I had opened in someday, like a history. It still finding any files when **any branch is openned**, but **when I open the trunk**, the IDE finds all files, **unless .jsps** extensions.

I have already compared the project properties and did not find any difference until now. I tried to compare the nbproject folder, but there is too much difference that I'm getting lost looking for the dumb difference.

I appreciate any tips everyone. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem after erasing Netbeans's cache.

Temp location: C:\Users[username].netbeans\7.1.2\var\cache

Thank you!